# Using two 30amp circuits to supply one range

Tags: electrical, wiring, stove

My old range from the 1970s has two 30A circuits coming to it.  New ranges all use a single 40A circuit.  Can I join the two sets of wires into a single 60A breaker?  The circuits would be joined at both ends to a new 60A wiring, one to range and one to new breaker.

Comment: Where are you located?  What is the make and model of the new range?

Comment: Looking around it seems I can't do what I suggest!  I'm in the Bay Area. No range yet, I'm looking on craigslist

Comment: What is the wire size at the breaker and receptacle? Should be the same but you never know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bottom line is NO, you definitely cannot do what you propose. You CANNOT parallel a circuit like this of this size. It is expressly forbidden in the NEC, and could very well be a safety hazard.

If the appliance takes two separate circuits like your old one that is a different story. Do you know what size and type of wire is feeding the old 30A circuits?

Also, all "new ranges" definitely do not use a 40A circuit. Many can, but many also have too great a draw for a 40A circuit.

The NEC allows any household cooking appliance 12kW or under to be served by a 40A circuit, but I see more and more basic units over 12kW.